# Swift: How do unit test UIWebView loading?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, uiwebview

My app has a basic webview controller to perform some operations.  This view in the storyboard is not much besides a wrapper around a UIWebView.  The controller itself has various public functions that can be called to load pages in the webview, like so:

```
class WebViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

  // MARK: Properties

  @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

  // MARK: UIViewController

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.delegate = self
    loadHomePage()
  }

  // MARK: Public

  public func loadHomePage() {
    navigateWebView(to: HOME_PAGE)
  }

  public func loadSettingsPage() {
    navigateWebView(to: SETTINGS_PAGE)
  }

  public func loadSignOutPage() {
    navigateWebView(to: SIGN_OUT_PAGE)
  }

  // MARK: Private

  private func navigateWebView(to url: String) {
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
  }
```

I'm trying to write unit tests that verify that the proper URL is sent to the loadRequest function of the webview.  Note that I don't actually care about loading the URL; this is just a unit test, so all I really want to test is that loadSettingsPage sends a URLRequest with the SETTINGS_PAGE URL to the webview to load, for example.

I tried something like this, with no success:

```
_ = webViewController.view  // Calls viewDidLoad()   
XCTAssertEqual(webViewController.webView.request?.url?.absoluteString, HOME_PAGE)
```

The value of the first part of the assertEqual was nil.

I assume I need to mock out the webView somehow but I'm not sure how to go about that.  Any suggestions?

As a follow-up, I'd also like to be able to test when things like `webView.reload()` and `webview.goBack()` are called, so any pointers there would be appreciated as well.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you should avoid testing the webView directly and mock your viewController a little more abstract. Instead of testing the webView loading the request test that navigateWebView receives the write URL. And if you want to make sure you're building the request properly maybe break that into another method thats more easily testable

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?